# Assembly loop doesn't work

Tags: loops, assembly, fibonacci

Im trying to do a loop that calculate the first 10 number in Fibonacci number.
I use "loop" at the and of the code, and it doesn't work.

```
    xor cx, cx
    mov cx, 8
    mov bx, offset Array
    mov [byte ptr bx], 0
    mov [byte ptr bx+1], 1
    mov bx, 1

Fibo:
    inc bx
    mov al, [byte ptr bx-1]
    mov [byte ptr bx], al
    mov al, [byte ptr bx-2]
    add [byte ptr bx], al
    loop Fibo
```

Comment: You should avoid `loop`. It's slow, and implicitly uses `[r/e]cx`, which means that in 32- or 64-bit mode the code you've posted could loop much more than you expect.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659715/assembly-language-x86-how-to-create-a-loop-to-calculate-fibonacci-sequence

Answer (score 1):

The loop is OK, but you destroy your `bx` by accident. Try to debug it with debugger.

(downvoting, because it's *obvious* if you debug it, even on paper without HW).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use "byte ptr [bx]" instead of "[byte ptr bx]" for all of your pointer types.

Also, this line is probably going to cause a bug.

```
mov bx, 1
```

It resets bx, so it won't point to the address of Array anymore. Use "inc bx" instead.

Comment: But when I use Instead of "loop", that:                                                                                         dec cx-
cmp cx, 0-
jne Fibo -                                                                                                    It works.

Comment: There are many ways that this can still work. One of the being that Array's relative address in memory being 0. But you want a program that always works. Not one that just works sometimes. :)

Answer (score 1):

The loop was correct.
I was confused about how to debug loops.
sorry.