# NASM - JBE instruction gives segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am trying to implement a fibonacci algorithm in assembly using the NASM assembler.
This is the pseudo code for the algorithm

```
fibonacci_it(n):
    int f_i-1 = 1;
    int f_i-2 = 1;

    if (n==0):
        return 1;
    else:
        int i = 1;
        int f_i = 1;
        while (i < n):
            f_i = f_i-1 + f_i-2
            f_i-2 = f_i-1
            f_i-1 = f_i
            i = i + 1
        return f_i
```

What I've tried looks like this:

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .data
prompt      db  "Enter number: ", 0

segment .bss
fibnum      resd 1

segment .text
    global asm_main

asm_main:
    enter   0,0
    pusha   

    mov         eax, prompt
    call        print_string
    call        read_int
    mov         [fibnum], eax

    push        dword [fibnum]
    call        fib_it
    call        print_int

    popa
    mov         eax, 0
    leave
    ret



fib_it:
    enter   12,0                ; 3 local variables: f_i, f_i-1, f_i-2
    pusha

    mov     dword [ebp-4], 1    ; initialize f_i
    mov     dword [ebp-8], 1    ; initialize f_i-1
    mov     dword [ebp-12], 1   ; initialize f_i-2
    mov     ecx, 1              ; i = 1
    mov     edx, 1              ; comparison operator for n
    cmp     [ebp+8], edx        ; n <= 1 ?
    jbe     end_fib_it          ; if n <= 1 -> end and return 1

fib_it_while:
    dump_regs 1
    mov     eax, [ebp-8]        ; eax = f_i-1
    add     eax, [ebp-12]       ; eax = f_i-1 + f_i-2
    mov     [ebp-4], eax        ; f_i = f_i-1 + f_i-2
    mov     eax, [ebp-8]        ; eax = f_i-1
    mov     [ebp-12], eax       ; f_i-2 = f_i-1
    mov     eax, [ebp-4]        ; eax = f_i
    mov     [ebp-8], eax        ; f_i-1 = f_i
    inc     ecx                 ; i += 1
    cmp     ecx, [ebp+8]        ; i < n ?
    jae     end_fib_it          ; end while loop if i < n
    jmp     fib_it_while        ; else -> loop again

end_fib_it:
    mov     eax, [ebp-4]        ; return f_i
    popa
    leave
    ret
```

The program first reads an integer from the terminal. Then it pushes this to the stack as parameter for fib_it
When I run the program it gives a segmentation fault. I found out that every time `jbe end_fib_it` or `jae end_fib_it` is true and the program has to jump then it gives a segmentation fault. I've made some more debugging with `dump_regs` and found out that the while loop runs perfectly and `jmp fib_it_while` gives no problems.

Comment: Keeping all your data in memory instead of registers is very slow.  `add eax,edx` / `add edx,eax` computes the Fibonacci sequence much more efficiently!  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659715/assembly-language-x86-how-to-create-a-loop-to-calculate-fibonacci-sequence for some good ways to write it, starting from fairly simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found out that every time jbe end_fib_it or jae end_fib_it is true and the program has to jump then it gives a segmentation fault.

Your observation might not be the problem at all.

> ```
> push        dword [fibnum]
> call        fib_it
> ```

When you call fib_it, you push a dword on the stack **and you don't pop it anywhere afterwards.**

The simplest of solutions is probably to end fib_it with an alternate form of `ret`:

```
popa
leave
ret 4      ; The 4 will remove the parameter from the stack
```

---

### Don't use `pusha`/`popa`

> ```
> end_fib_it:
>   mov     eax, [ebp-4]        ; return f_i
>   popa
> ```

You want to return a result in `EAX`, **but the `popa` instruction that follows will immediately destroy what you've just put in there!**

Since you're only using the additional registers `ECX` and `EDX`, best change `pusha` into `push ecx` `push edx`. Also change `popa` into `pop edx` `pop ecx`.

---

### Optimization

> ```
> mov     edx, 1              ; comparison operator for n
> cmp     [ebp+8], edx        ; n <= 1 ?
> ```

Why would you use the additional register `EDX` if all you're using it for is a single comparison?
If you change this pair of instructions into:

```
cmp     dword [ebp+8], 1        ; n <= 1 ?
```

the forementioned replacement for `pusha`/`popa` will only be `push ecx`/`pop ecx`.

Comment: @Codey I've added an optimization.

Comment: `enter 0,0` is also very slow.  If you want to talk about optimization, using memory for everything (and copying it around like the OP is doing) is about 12 to 18x slower than a simple `add eax, edx` / `add edx, eax` on Intel Haswell for example.  At least they decided to keep the loop counter in a register, and use the loop upper-bound read-only.  (Much better than the other way around, with an RMW for `inc [mem]` and another load for a `cmp`.)

Comment: For a decent asm Fibonacci (which stores the sequence in an array), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32661389/224132.  The first version is just a simple one-at-a-time version with register `mov`.  Later versions are unrolled with various optimizations to the intro code :)