# How to restore x86-64 register saving conventions

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, calling-convention

```
fibonacci:
         cmpq    $1, %rdi
         ja      .recursive
         movl    $1, %eax
         ret
.recursive:
         push    %rbp
         push    %r10
         movq    %rdi, %r10
         leaq    -2(%rdi), %rdi
         call    fibonacci
         movq    %rax, %rbp
         leaq    -1(%r10), %rdi
         call    fibonacci
         addq    %rbp, %rax
         pop     %r10
         pop     %rbp
         ret
```

How do I restore the x86-64 register saving conventions.

I'm not sure how to do this, but here's my train of thought. %r10 is a caller-saved register, so it needs to be saved before and after calls to other methods. In this situation, we need to save %r10 only if it is used after a recursive call to fibonacci. Still, I'm not  sure where to add instructions to restore register saving  conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> %r10 is a caller-saved register, so it needs to be saved before and after calls to other methods.

Not if you avoid keeping anything precious in it!  You're falling into the trap created by the clumsy "caller-saved" terminology, as if that means you *have* to save it instead of just letting tmp values die.  I prefer **[call-preserved vs. call-clobbered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers/56178078#56178078)**

**Pick a call-preserved register like RBX for values that you want to survive across calls, and save/restore it *once* at the start/end of your function**.  Exactly like you're doing with RBP.  You *could* do that with R10, since the only calls your function makes are to itself.  But if you want to follow the x86-64 System V calling convention exactly (i.e. only assume that calling yourself preserves the call-preserved registers), use RBX, RBP, or R12..R15.  [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call)

As an optimization, you can make do with only 1 call-preserved register by using it for N at first, then for the first Fib result.

Just for fun I made the input `N` a 32-bit integer; no need to use 64-bit integer inputs; Fib(94) overflows a 64-bit integer!  This should make it easier to see when I'm dealing with N (32-bit registers) vs. Fib(N) (64-bit registers).  Remember that writing a 32-bit register implicitly zero-extends into the full 64-bit register.

```
## Recursive is a terribly inefficient way to implement Fibonacci
## but if you must do it this way (without memoization or anything), this may be less bad than most, only using 16 bytes of stack per depth of call.
recursive_fib:    # unsigned long fib(unsigned N)
    cmp    $1, %edi 
    ja    .Lnon_basecase
    mov    %edi, %eax                ## bugfix: Fib(0) = 0, Fib(1) = 1
    ret

.Lnon_basecase:
    push   %rbx              ###### save a call-preserved register
    mov    %edi, %ebx        # keep a copy of N for later
    dec    %edi
    call   recursive_fib            # Fib(N-1)
    lea    -2(%rbx), %edi    # read N
    mov    %rax, %rbx        # replace RBX with Fib(N-1)
    call   recursive_fib            # Fib(N-2)
    add    %rbx, %rax        # retval = Fib(N-2) + Fib(N-1)
    pop    %rbx              ###### restore caller's RBX
    ret
```

You *could* of course spill / reload RDI to the stack across the first `call`, either like a compiler would with a `mov` into space you reserved earlier with `sub $16, %rsp`, or with actual push/pop.  **You'd need to do it this way if you ran out of call-preserved registers in a large function.**

(But hopefully you can choose to spill something that's read-mostly: re-reading memory is cheap, updating memory creates store/reload latency bottlenecks.  This is why compilers have smart register-allocation algorithms)

(You only need 8 bytes of space, but a compiler would maintain x86-64 System V's 16-byte RSP alignment before a call.  That means the total RSP offset in any function before another call is `8 + 16*x`, and if you start with a `push %rbp` then you need to leave 16 bytes.  By hand you know you're only calling yourself, and that this function doesn't care about stack alignment.)

---

BTW, recursive Fibonacci takes O(Fib(N)) time vs. O(N) for a simpler loop that uses the last 2 values.  Fun fact, `xadd %rdx, %rax` in a loop implements Fibonacci, or unroll with 2 `add` instructions.  [Assembly Language (x86): How to create a loop to calculate Fibonacci sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659715/assembly-language-x86-how-to-create-a-loop-to-calculate-fibonacci-sequence/32661389#32661389)